# access ibm cloud private dash board

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I have installed ICP within a private newtork. And each VM having public IP address. I am able to access ICP dashboard using master node private IP address (https://master-node-private-ip:8443).

But I am not able to access using master node public IP address (https://master-node-public-ip:8443). I tried with setting cluster_lb_address:  in config.yaml file.

But it doesn't work.

Comment: It could be due to security groups in your vm, I recommend to check them through the portal page, it should be in the main page of virtual guest (after the network section)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

In config.yaml file, uncomment and set both your cluster_lb_address and proxy_lb_address to the master node public IP address. In cluster/hosts file, all the IPs must have the same subnet.

Example:

```
# cat cluster/hosts
[master]
172.16.151.126

[worker]
172.16.151.182
172.16.155.135

[proxy]
172.16.151.126

#[management]
#4.4.4.4

#[va]
#5.5.5.5

config.yaml
------------------------------
cluster_lb_address: 9.x.x.x
proxy_lb_address: 9.x.x.x
```